# Reading the textvalue line by line using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I really tried this a lot but I haven't got any result that actually worked. 
I want to read the text of html textarea line by line using JQuery. Textarea has a fixed width and height. For example if the text area has the text like:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br/>
aaaaaaaaaaaaa just typed a real long<br/>
word that wont fit in side of this part of<br/>
div
```

I would like to have a string as

```
'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa< br /> aaaaaaaaaaaaa just typed a real long< br />
word that wont fit in side of this part of <br />div
```

I've tried it and it did not work out. Any suggestions?

Comment: Within a textarea, does the text use \r\n or \n to represent a newline?  If so, you can find these instances and replace them with <br/>, but not sure if it does that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JavaScript's [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function on the newline character `\n`. Then, call [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) on the resulting array.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/XjN72/1/

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response! I've tried to do it and applied it in my code:   var values = $('#comment').val().split('\n');
 var stringToShow=values.join('<br/>');
 $('#commentArea').html(stringToShow); The purpose was to get that string and put it in a div. But it did not work out in this div <div id='commentArea' style='width:510px;height:85px;border:1px solid black;padding:5px;font-family:Ariel,sans-serif;font-size:12px;'>
 </div>.  The reason I wanna have this string is because i will save it in my database and later put it in a div with JQuery's html function.

Comment: Does this work in all browsers? I am working with this problem myself but the fiddle didn't work, using Chrome. But it did work in Firefox.

Comment: Tried it in Chrome 23/Windows and it works. What are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the newlines:

```
text = text.replace(/\n|\r/g, "");
```